# "The goal update-theme requires Vaadin 7.1 or later"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin7

All I want to do is extend the existing Vaadin theme called "Valo".

I'm using IntelliJ and Maven.

In my UI class:

```
@Theme("myTheme")
...
public class MyUI extends UI {
    ...
}
```

I've added styles.scss at src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/myTheme containing the following content:

```
$v-font-size: 12px;

$v-unit-size: 26px;
$v-unit-size--small: 20px;
$v-unit-size--tiny: 18px;

$v-layout-margin-top: 18px;
$v-layout-margin-right: 18px;
$v-layout-margin-bottom: 18px;
$v-layout-margin-left: 18px;
$v-layout-spacing-vertical: 7px;
$v-layout-spacing-horizontal: 6px;

@import "../valo/valo";
```

In my pom.xml I included the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
  <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And there I have veryfied the resources:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I get this error when trying to access my site:

`Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/styles.css] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.`

I guess that this is because the scss-file needs to be compiled.

To do so I added the following plugin in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>update-theme</goal>
                <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                <!--
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>resources</goal>
                <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                -->
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When compiling the project I get the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:7.6.0.alpha2:updat
e-theme (default) on project classification-tool-webapp: The goal update-theme r
equires Vaadin 7.1 or later -> [Help 1]`

Comment: not loading as in "it takes longer" and everything is unstyled?  do you get any errors? if your VaadinServlet runs in production mode, you have to have the styles.CSS in place.  in debug mode it will compile scss on the fly - but you will have to find out, how to compile the theme anyway for your fat-jar/war.

Comment: I've updated my question and tried to be more specific.

Comment: i dont use maven, so i cant test, but that error could as well be false positive.  you might want to try 7.5.10 - also the current 7.6 is beta2

Comment: Where is your Maven property `${vaadin.version}` defined?

Comment: Hi did u manged to solve this error? I am facing same issue

Comment: @Kirby I have defined ${vaadin.version} in my parent POM. will that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Make sure that you have correct [com.vaadin:vaadin-shared](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-shared) dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-shared</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: this dependency doesn't have to be explicit. You may already have it via other dependencies (e.g. [com.vaadin:vaadin-server](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-server)). Check your pom.xml

**MORE DETAILS**

[Vaadin maven plugin](https://github.com/vaadin/maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/integration/maven/AbstractThemeMojo.java) checks the Vaadin version using the following code:

```
protected boolean isAtLeastVaadinVersion(int major, int minor) {
    // find "vaadin-shared" and check its version
    for (Artifact artifact : getProjectArtifacts()) {
        if (VAADIN_GROUP_ID.equals(artifact.getGroupId())
                && "vaadin-shared".equals(artifact.getArtifactId())) {
            // TODO this is an ugly hack because Maven does not tolerate
            // version numbers of the form "7.1.0.beta1"
            String artifactVersion = artifact.getVersion();
 (...)
```

In short, it goes through all dependencies looking for com.vaadin:vaadin-shared with specific version. It doesn't check actual jar but rather their maven metadata. That means that you may already have the correct JAR, for example with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>vaadin-shared-7.7.12</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-shared-7.7.12</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>lib/vaadin-shared-7.7.12.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

but still the check in Vaadin maven plugin would fail. And you would get the exception

> The goal update-theme requires Vaadin 7.1 or later

And vice versa - you may "cheat" the plugin having:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-shared</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>lib/fake.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

(where *fake.jar* IS NOT *vaadin-shared.jar*) and you'll pass the check (theme compilation won't work though, as you need the classes either way).
So the solution for that exception is to make sure that you have the correct vaadin-shared with correct version.